# Restrict users to access routes in flask

Tags: flask, bokeh, flask-login

I am trying to create a flask app that will allow users to login, thereafter, they will be redirected to a specific dashboard created and being served with Bokeh.

So, for example, we have an **user1**, at the beginning he will start in https:myurl/**login**, after successful login he will be redirected to https:myurl/**user1** where his  specific dashboard is.

So, my question is, how I can avoid user1 accessing dashboard from other users user2, user3, etc. It is actually possible to do that? I am relatively new to flask, so my apologies if the question sounds silly.

```
from multiprocessing import connection
from functools import wraps
from re import A
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session
import sqlite3


from sqlalchemy import DATE

# Setup
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "my_key"

# Routes
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        connection = sqlite3.connect("user_login.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Get what the user has typed in the HTML form
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        # SQL query
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password)
        )
        data = cursor.fetchone()

        if data:
            session["username"] = data[1]
            session["password"] = data[2]
            return redirect(url_for("user({data[1]})"))
            # return redirect(f"https://myurl/{session['username']}", code=302)
        else:
            flash("Username and Password Mismatch", "DANGER! Please try again")

    # Render HTML template
    return render_template("login.html")


# Check if user is logged in
# def is_logged_in(f):
#     @wraps(f)
#     def secure_function(*args, **kwargs):
#         if "logged_in" in session:
#             return f(*args, **kwargs)
#         else:
#             flash("Unauthorized, please login", "danger")
#             return redirect(url_for("login"))
#     return secure_function


@app.route("/<username>")
def user(username):
    if username == session['username']:
        return redirect(
            f"https://myurl/{session['username']}", code=302
        )
    else:
        return flash("Unauthorized")


# @app.route('/')
# def logged():
#     return redirect(f"https://myurl/{session['username']}", code=302)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your current code please

Comment: @0m3r here it goes! I am connecting to a SQLITE db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about verifying if the

```
current_user.username == myurl/<username>
```

.username being the name of your user in your Models(if it is name then current_user.name, etc.)

Like

```py
@app.route("/dashboard/<username>")
def dashboard(username):
    if username == current_user.username:
        #proceed
    else:
        return "Access Denied"
```

*** Edit ***

Your provided code for the return statement

```py
redirect(url_for("user({data[1]})"))
```

Could be written as:

```py
return redirect(url_for('user', username = data[1]))
```

Comment: Well, this is actually what I have been trying to implement and, so far, isn't working. I have posted the actual code from my app.py if that helps.

Comment: So you are not using *the* flask-login module? If not yet then I suggest you take a look of it, I recommeded the answer due to the question being tagged with *flask-login*, a module to handle login and user authentication.***also out of scope of the problem, I suggest you could also use some flask_sqlalchemy to avoid doing tons of hand coded SQL***

Comment: Also for your provided code redirect(url_for("user({data[1]})")) isn't this line missing a f before the quotation. I'll edit the code with an alternative way for the redirect to work

Comment: Ohh, got it! Thanks for that! Now is working. I will include your suggestions on my next version!